# CanvasJS data formatting, adding text to X/Y labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

I've got a big problem with number formatting in CanvasJS and I tried almost every combination but can't get the result I want. As you can see on the SS for point 2 on X label I got result 28,...,...,102.368003 and the I want it to be shown as 28564...102.37 so after decimal point just two numbers and no commas in the result.

Second problem is, how do I show the Y label (label where it say "Power received") the text selected in box (red square where it's written "W") so it would be "Powere received [W]" so it would be "Power received ["text-selected-in-box"]".

the code is in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6OQ5.png)

Comment: Have you tried something like ####.## or #########.## for the number format? I'm assuming you have read the docs on the number formatting https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/formatting-numbers/